# Visual Studio - purpose of 'Refresh' button in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, refresh, solution-explorer

what's the purpose of the 'Refresh' command on the solution explorer window? 
(When we select a project, the button is enabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really helpful when you have Show All Files is turned on in a Web application project (this might work for other project types). With the Refresh, you can see files added on the file system level and right-click them to include them in your project.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an overly simple response, but I use the refresh button quite often to populate the Solution Explorer with files that have been created outside of VS.

For example, I use a separate IDE to do my Actionscript work where lots of files get added which VS is not aware of until I refresh the solution explorer window.  After they appear, I can now commit them to SourceSafe.

Answer (score 1):

If you have version control integration, the tree view is decorated with source control status annotations.  Refresh updates these when they get out of sync.

Comment: Exactly. -- Now does anyone know where to find this button in 2013? -- It seems to be missing.